# Why is mocking out zeep.Client not working?

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I'm writing unit tests for a piece of code that uses zeep to access a SOAP API so I want to mock out zeep. In my actual code, it looks something like this:

```
from zeep import Client

def do_something():
    client = Client("...")
```

In my test, I'm doing this:

```
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch('zeep.Client')
def test_do_somethi(self, MockedClient):
    do_something()
```

The `Client` that the actual function is obtaining, is the actual zeep client and not my mock. I also tried:

```
@mock.patch('zeep.client.Client')
```

and the result was the same.

I also tried:

```
def test_do_something(self):
  with mock.patch('zeep.client.Client') as MockedClient:
     do_something()
```

with no difference.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When mock doesn't work, the first thing to look for is if you are  patching the right name. Three common import scenarios:

(a) If you want to mock out `zeep` but you import like

```
from zeep import Client
```

and your tests are in the same file, you patch `Client` not `zeep.Client`.

(b) If instead you import it like

```
import zeep
```

and then use `zeep.Client` in SUT code, then you patch `zeep.Client`.

(c) If you are testing code that lies in some other module (like `mymodule`) and you import `zeep` there with

```
from zeep import Client # (1)
```

then in your test module you

```
import mymodule
```

then you patch `mymodule.Client`, ... or `mymodule.zeep.Client` if you used the alternative `import zeep` form in (1).

Answer (score 1):

You must patch the method/class from file you are using it. If you want to patch `Client` and it is imported in **some_file.py** you must import it from it, and not from lib (`zeep.Client`)

Here is an example using the [official doc](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/#a-simple-use-case) from Zeep.

**some_lib.py**

```
from zeep import Client

def do_something():
    wsdl = 'http://www.soapclient.com/xml/soapresponder.wsdl'
    client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)
    return client.service.Method1('Zeep', 'is cool')
```

**test_connection.py**

```
from some_lib import do_something
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('some_lib.Client')
def test_do_something(mock_zeep):
    res = do_something()
    assert mock_zeep.call_count == 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_soap_conn()
```